# Chat screen continuously loading

Tags: bug, chat, android-app

I have clicked on the chat link provided by one user in comment secrion. And clicking on that redirected me to chat screen. I was able to see all comments there but screens keeps refreshing by itself. I had to close it then.

[My Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ORZKyAZrrmd3dLbmFzQzlIdEE/view?usp=drivesdk)

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: Moto G (4)

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (64)

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little more in text?

Comment: I'll take this opportunity to say that stack exchange's chat is not attractive.  I'm not sure if that's the only reason I don't use it but perhaps it could use work.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have updated my answer and you can view the video as well.

Comment: The link to the video will die eventually. Text remains forever. Also, Google likes text.

Comment: @PatrickHofman actually I was using stackoverflow and got redirected from there.

Comment: Yeah, the "inline browser" used by the app doesn't really support chat, you need to open it in actual browser.